# NULL and nullptr comparison

Tags: c++

Is it safe to compare pointers where one is **NULL** and other is **nullptr**?
Will that comparison always give true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Both `NULL` and `nullptr` are *"null pointer constants"* and

> A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type
>   and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type.

Lastly,

> Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal.

(Both quotes 4.10/1 in N4140)

Comment: Just to remind that there is only one "nullptr" shared by all pointer types.

Comment: If I compare `(nullptr == NULL)` I get `error: comparison between NULL and non-pointer ('std::nullptr_t' and NULL) [-Werror,-Wnull-arithmetic]` in clang ☹

Comment: @mirabilos That is comparing the `NULL` literal to `nullptr`, which is different to the scenario discussed here: comparing two pointers where one has been assigned `NULL` and the other `nullptr`. The important difference is that `NULL` is usually not a pointer in C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen but the compiler complains not about `NULL` not being a pointer but about `nullptr` not being one. (But someone on Fedi helped me, casting either one to `void *` fixes that.)

Comment: @mirabilos Sure, this question is about comparing pointers, your scenario is comparing null pointer constants. As you have discovered, null pointer constants are not pointers, so this answer doesn't apply to your scenario. By casting at least one of the null pointer constants to pointer, you change your scenario to the pointer comparison.

Comment: @BaummitAugen ok, then it’s the CFrustFrust part of null pointer constants not being pointers that confused me. That totally makes no sense to me, but, alas, if it’s what the committee decided, so be it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `NULL` is `0` (either through a `#define` or an integral type definition) then, yes.

Comment: In C++ the standard `NULL` is always `0`, of some integral type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf As of C++11, it may also be a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Interseting.  All I got from the C++ standards was: `The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard`.  Thinking about it, that *must* means as you say.

Comment: @PaulEvans *"A null pointer constant is an integer literal with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`."* Also 4.10/1 in N4140.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks, that ties it all together.